# Laravel con Varias Bases de Datos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Trato de acceder con una nueva conexion a una base de datos diferente pero el `Eloquent` continua buscando en la primera conexion; este es el error que me genera

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.padron' doesn't exist (42S02)

claramente no lo va encontrar ya que esta buscando la `blog.padron` la tabla **padron** en la DB `blog`, puesto que esta en la BD `kodo` es la que tiene la tabla **padron** cuya conexion deberia ir a **kodo.padron**

```css
**Metodo**

public function padron($id) {
    //$pa=\App\Padron::on(\Session::get('kodo'))->where("id",$id)->get();

    /*$pa=new \App\Padron();
    $pa->setConnection('kodo');
    $ls=$pa->where("id",$id)->get();
    */
    return $pa;
}

**Modelo**

class Padron extends Model{
    protected $connection ='kodo';
    protected $table='padron';
}
```

```html
**Confiuracion de la Base se Datos**

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'kodo'  => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'latin1',
            'collation' => 'latin1_general_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
        ],

    ],

    /*
        DB_CONNECTION=mysql
        DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
        DB_PORT=3306
        DB_DATABASE=blog
        DB_USERNAME=roots
        DB_PASSWORD=123456

        PADRON_CONNECTION=mysql
        PADRON_HOST=127.0.0.1
        PADRON_PORT=3306
        PADRON_DATABASE=kodo
        PADRON_USERNAME=roots
        PADRON_PASSWORD=123456
    */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues te falta asignar los valores correctos de tu archivo `.env` en la conexión correspondiente:

Tu archivo `.env`:

```
PADRON_CONNECTION=mysql
PADRON_HOST=127.0.0.1
PADRON_PORT=3306
PADRON_DATABASE=kodo
PADRON_USERNAME=roots
PADRON_PASSWORD=123456
```

Tu archivo de configuración:

```
'kodo'  => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('PADRON_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), //estabas poniendo el mismo valor de 'DB_HOST' en estos datos
            'port' => env('PADRON_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('PADRON_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('PADRON_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('PADRON_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'latin1',
            'collation' => 'latin1_general_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
        ],
```

Asegúrate de correr el comando `php artisan config:cache` después de realizar estos cambios.